# (GRE) How to best determine standard deviation from frequency distribution

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

[image]

The full question asks whether $s_A > s_B$, $s_A < s_B$, $s_A = s_B$, or it is impossible to determine.

By doing hand calculations, I found that $s_A\approx 13.8$ and $s_B\approx 16.45$. Is there a way to reason that the standard deviation of B should be bigger than A without doing many calculations?

Comment: Can you compute the mean in each case?  In which instance are data points more likely to be concentrated near the mean?

Comment: There is *never* an instance on the ordinary GRE where you need to explicitly calculate a standard deviation. The problems are conceptual and meant to trap those who insist on doing irrelevant, explicit calculations.

Comment: @lulu: re your first question, calculating the means is irrelevant, of course; it does not matter that both distributions have mean 30. shift the second distribution by any constant and the result is the same. (I know you know this; just adding for the OP.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, standard deviation is supposed to give a measure of how much the datapoints deviate from the mean (and therefore from each other). If datapoints are all clustered together, the standard deviation is small; if spread out, it's large.

In Distribution A, there are more datapoints clustered near the mean (the middle value, 30) than spread out at the edges. Distribution B is exactly the opposite situation: most of the data is at the edges, and very little in the middle. Thus Distribution B is more spread out and should have a higher standard deviation.